# what is use of location while we create table in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

i created table in hive as

```
create table table1(id in,name string)
row format delimited
fields terminated by ','
stored as textfile
location'/home/training/desktop/shared/EMP_DATA.txt'
```

i want to know what is use of location even it does not load data into table
verified by

```
select * from table;
```

so what is use of location

Comment: LOCATION is a **directory**. You cannot point to a specific file; Hive will read all files there *(except the special files such as `__SUCCESS` etc)* on SELECT, and will create 1..N new file(s) per INSERT *(1 per reducer job)*

Comment: Plus, LOCATION is a **HDFS directory**, accessible from Hadoop jobs running on any YARN node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Location is used to override default hive table directory. It tells where the data will be stored for a table.

Comment: i gave the location as  = location'/home/training/desktop/new file2.txt'  but no such file is created on desktop  after creating table.so how would i can know that location is working

Comment: It is  HDFS Directory, it will create a file when u insert data in the table

Comment: NOTE: Hive stores tables files by default at `/user/hive/warehouse` location on the HDFS file system.